# How to fetch the url of the function inside function

Tags: jquery

The following is the function adn i want to grab its url through jquery, is this possible:

```
function generate() {

    url = "http://example.com/abc.asp?sortOrder=1";
    mywin = window.open (url,"win",'resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=878,height=810');
    mywin.focus();
    return false;
}
```

i want to fetch the url of the above function, using jquery to do it, but not sure how to do it..

this is a requirement, i canot change the function in anycase, as it is not in my control

Comment: Seeing as your variables are global (you forgot to use the `var` keyword) you don't need jQuery, the variable is available anywhere ?

Comment: the tricky part here is the above code function is in different domain and i am loading that domain in my container, so i need to find this function and fetch its url and then i can create my own function on my own site

Comment: And how exactly are you loading that "domain", that would probably change the question completely and is relevant information ?

Comment: i am using server side language to call that domain through cfhttp [coldfusion]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems your `url` var is local. Then, there is no way to grab its value from another scope.

Either you can edit the function and, for instance, return the url. Or, if `url` is a global var (its declaration `var url;` has been done outside your function), you are able to use it everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

you can surely do that just by assigning the variable "url" to a property as below:

```
function generate() {

        this.url = "http://example.com/abc.asp?sortOrder=1";
        var mywin = window.open(this.url, "win", 'resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=878,height=810');
        mywin.focus();
        //return false;
    }
    var a = new generate();
    alert(a.url);
```

Hope this helps :)